# how to pass value in single row and multiple column

Tags: selenium, web-applications, testng

I need to handle webtable to pass the value specific column [as here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K19t.png).

```
 String p=" Ease 3.0   | $849";
 WebElement Product=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[text()='"+p+"']//parent::div//following-sibling::div[1]//div[1]//div[2]"));

 WebElement findp=Product.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));

 List<WebElement> great=findp.findElements(By.xpath("tr"));

 int rowcount=great.size();

 System.out.println(rowcount);

 for(int i=0;i<=great.size();i++)
 {
        XSSFRow foundRow =sheet.getRow(i);

        List<WebElement> column_row=great.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        int columncount=column_row.size();

        System.out.println("total number of row"+rowcount+"columns are"+columncount);
}
```

But I am getting the below error . Please anyone help on this.

> FAILED: Allproduct java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1,
>   Size: 1   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access index that out of the range in the list.

```
for(int i=0;i<=great.size();i++)
```

You are checking the *i* to be smaller or equal to list's size, but it is wrong.

Assume that the list has 3 elements `[1,2,3]`. The count will return 3, but the index of the last element is 2 (it is zero based). When you are trying to access the index 3, the exception will be thrown.